# Why QueryDict returns a list when checking for an object?

Tags: python, django

i'm tring a thing with `**` operator

i've this function

```
def splitData(data, operation, n=0, m=0):
    ..
    log.debug("data: %s",data)
    ...
```

and i call it from an API (django-rest-framework) view that takes data from a `POST`

so what i do is this

```
log.debug("data from get %s",request.DATA.get('data','[]'))

res = splitData(**request.DATA)
```

result is correct

```
data from get [{'id':1,'a1':1},{'id':2,'a1':2}]
```

while the output form the debug inside the `splitData` function is this

```
data: [u"[{'id':1,'a1':1},{'id':2,'a1':2}]"]
```

why the `data` that is taken from the `**request.DATA` is a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(There's no such thing as `request.DATA` - presumably you mean `request.REQUEST`. Please post actual code in future.)

This has nothing to do with kwargs.

It is because request data is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object, which is customised to allow multiple values for each key.

Comment: request.DATA comes from `django-rest-framework`. thanks for the link, so it seems that i should do something like [0] to get the first item. is there anything to get only 1 item?
PS: i change the title than.